# Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

Tags: eclipse, modeling, eclipse-sirius

When I want to install a plugin Obeo Designer on eclipse modeling I have this error :

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Sirius Specification Environment 3.1.7.201611021249 (org.eclipse.sirius.specifier.ide.ui.feature.group 3.1.7.201611021249)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Modeling Tools 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (epp.package.modeling 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    PDE Core 3.11.1.v20161115-1951 (org.eclipse.pde.core 3.11.1.v20161115-1951)
    PDE Core 3.8.1.v20130115-200504 (org.eclipse.pde.core 3.8.1.v20130115-200504)
    PDE Core 3.10.102.v20160128-0556 (org.eclipse.pde.core 3.10.102.v20160128-0556)
    PDE Core 3.8.0.v20120606-170547 (org.eclipse.pde.core 3.8.0.v20120606-170547)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse Workbench User Guide 4.2.0.v20120829-072800 (org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 4.2.0.v20120829-072800)
    Eclipse Workbench User Guide 4.6.1.v20160727-2009 (org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 4.6.1.v20160727-2009)
    Eclipse Workbench User Guide 4.2.2.v20130121-200410 (org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 4.2.2.v20130121-200410)
    Eclipse Workbench User Guide 4.5.1.v20150819-1130 (org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 4.5.1.v20150819-1130)
    Eclipse Workbench User Guide 4.2.0.v20120606-135340 (org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 4.2.0.v20120606-135340)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Modeling Tools 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (epp.package.modeling 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.feature.feature.group [1.5.1.20120917-1257]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EPP Modeling Feature 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.feature.feature.group 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO]
```

Comment: eclipse version please ?

Comment: Eclipse Modeling Tools

Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think obeo-designer doesn't support Juno, I would recommend Luna,

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/obeo-designer-community

Supported versions: Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Oxygen (4.7), Neon (4.6)

Comment: Yup, Let me know if that helped

Comment: Glad that it helped :)